# to what extent can a developer control what is in the cache?

Tags: php, javascript, caching

What can and can't be stored in it? Is it the same cross-browser? what php or javascript methods/functions directly control it? I'd like to know more about this in terms of speeding up or slowing down a website.

Comment: talking about browser cache or server side cache?

Comment: what cache are you talking about? APC?

Comment: Your question is highly ambiguous.

Comment: i guess which ever applies to my question the most. It didn't occur to me they were two separate things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only HTTP headers can manipulate the browser cache. They allow such things as expiry times to be set, and for the server to send a short "no changes" message instead of repeating a document (e.g. in response to an if-modified-since request).

mnot's [CACHING TUTORIAL for Web Authors and Webmasters](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) is essential reading.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not direct access for ECMAscript which can read/write the browsers cache. But there are some workarounds/indirect ways.

For instance, you can use a HTML5 cache manifest file or store certain data on your own by using the `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` (maybe even webSQL).

Another indirect control mechanism for the browser-cache are HTTP headers. Those headers can at least flush the cache for certain files/MIME types.